# Is there a block/mod to sync/link up block inventories?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-direwolf20

I'm setting up a mob farm, using auto spawners and grinders. I have the basics working, except at the moment, I need to go into the "killing room" to change the safari net. Is there a mod or block that I can use to kind of sync up the safari net slot, so I can change the net without needing to go into the room?

I'm using the DireWolf20 mod pack, but I'm open to adding new mods in.

Comment: The cursor from Open Blocks should work, once bound to the spawner (by sneak right clicking it with the cursor) it should allow to to remotely right click it by right clicking in air with the cursor (depending of config it may cost exp)... not exactly linking to the slot but should allow remote access to it

Answer (score 1):

Ender chests, which are in the Direwolf20 mod pack, sync up with each other provided they have the same color code (you can set the color code by clicking the 3 wool areas on the top of the chest with dyes)

Set up a system which can insert and extract a safari net in between the auto spawner and the ender chest. Eg: Use EnderIO conduits on In/Out mode, configured to extract from the ender chest or auto spawner when a redstone signal is applied

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Transvector Interface.  The transvector interface acts like the block its remotely linked to.  You can use a computer craft turtle to "open" the the transvector interface, take out the safari net and put in another one.  I haven't tested it, but Steve's Factory Manager might be able to do the same thing.

Direwolf20's 1.6.4 Let's Play series used a computer. Including a menu to let you choose the monster.  Looks at episodes [S6E102](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIeuH7y1V_o&list=PLaiPn4ewcbkFVpHSec5nvnY-HdU5Yptc_&index=103) and [S6E103](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBiWrSIKKew&index=104&list=PLaiPn4ewcbkFVpHSec5nvnY-HdU5Yptc_)